# No funciona justify-content:center en un flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

estoy haciendo un pricing grid con 3 secciones, en el cual al querer alinear los elementos (en este caso textos) adentro de estos le coloqué un `display:flex` al elemento padre, luego le cambié la dirección con un `flex-direction:column`, por lo que la dirección de las axis cambia, ahora quiero que los textos esten alineanos verticalmente por lo que le coloque `justify-content:center` pero no hace nada, no me los alinea y no tengo idea de por qué, podria hacer el pricing grid con grid si, pero quiero practicar esto de flex anidados

```
<div class="prices-container">
            <div class="prices-options">
                <div class="prices">
                        <h3>Plan 1</h3>
                        <p>Get the console for FREE!</p>
                        <p>Thats right we are NOT JOKING, you can have the console that you want for 0.00$</p>
                        <p>You think we're joking? Test us out NOW</p>
                        <a class="btn-price" href="#">Get this deal!</a>
                </div>
                <div class="prices">
                        <h3>Plan 2</h3>
                        <p>Get the console for twice the price</p>
                        <p>You get ONE console for the price of two!</p>
                        <p>What can be better than that?</p>
                        <a class="btn-price" href="#">Get this deal!</a>
                </div>
                <div class="prices">
                        <h3>Plan 3</h3>
                        <p>You gave your console to us</p>
                        <p>Yes yes, too amazing to be true</p>
                        <p>If your console is new, better!</p>
                        <a class="btn-price" href="#">Get this deal!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




  .prices-container {
        display:flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items:center;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .prices-options {
        flex-basis: 60%;
        display:flex;
        justify-content: center;
    
    }
    
    .prices {
        flex-basis: 700px;
        height: 360px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.185);
        margin: 0px 10px;
        border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.356);
        padding: 10px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center; /* No funciona */
      
    }
    
    
    
    .btn-price {
        background: rgba(230, 129, 129, 0.5);
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 5px;
        width: 70%; 
        border: 1px solid #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-top: auto;
        align-self: center;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .btn-price:hover {
        background: rgb(0,0,0,.3);
    }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar mejor el problema por favor?

Comment: agrega `text-align: center;` en la class `.prices`.
pero si queres que se centren con flexbox usa `align-items: center;` y no `justify-content: center;`

Comment: Lo que busco hacer es que los elementos o flex-items '<p>'  esten alineados dentro del contendor padre o flex-container que en este caso serian los '.prices' para eso coloqué 'justify-content:center' pero no los alinea en medio del contendor

Comment: `align-items` los alinea horizontalmente, mas no veticalmente. es el `margin-top:auto` del `btn-price` el que causa conflicto, pero me preguntaba si hay una manera de alinearlo tal y como tengo el codigo

Comment: ahora si te pude entender, ahora te subo la respuesta detallada!

Comment: Debes tener presente que ese height no ayuda mucho a evitar que tu contenido se desborde

Answer (score 0):

lo que Tenes que hacer es separarlos por mas `<div>` así usas el div del medio que contendrán la etiqueta `<p>` darle un valor de `width: 100%;` para que abarquen todo el contenedor de `.prices`.

te dejo el código de solución.

```css
.prices-container {
        display:flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items:center;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .prices-options {
        flex-basis: 60%;
        display:flex;
        justify-content: center;
    
    }
    
    .prices {
        flex-basis: 700px;
        height: 360px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.185);
        margin: 0px 10px;
        border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.356);
        padding: 10px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    
    .price-header {
        align-self: flex-start;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .price-body {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .price-footer {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        align-self: flex-end;
    }
    .btn-price {
        background: rgba(230, 129, 129, 0.5);
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 5px;
        width: 70%; 
        border: 1px solid #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .btn-price:hover {
        background: rgb(0,0,0,.3);
    }
```

```html
<div class="prices-container">
    <div class="prices-options">
        <div class="prices">
            <div class="price-header">
               <h3>Plan 1</h3> 
            </div>
            <div class="price-body">
                <p>Get the console for FREE!</p>
                <p>Thats right we are NOT JOKING, you can have the console that you want for 0.00$</p>
                <p>You think we're joking? Test us out NOW</p>
            </div>
            <div class="price-footer">
               <a class="btn-price" href="#">Get this deal!</a> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="prices">
            <div class="price-header">
               <h3>Plan 2</h3> 
            </div>
            <div class="price-body">
                <p>Get the console for twice the price</p>
                <p>You get ONE console for the price of two!</p>
                <p>What can be better than that?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="price-footer">
               <a class="btn-price" href="#">Get this deal!</a> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="prices">
            <div class="price-header">
               <h3>Plan 3</h3> 
            </div>
            <div class="price-body">
                <p>You gave your console to us</p>
                <p>Yes yes, too amazing to be true</p>
                <p>If your console is new, better!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="price-footer">
               <a class="btn-price" href="#">Get this deal!</a> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

cualquier cosa me avisas, suerte!

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que justify-content: center no se aplica ya que los elementos .prices están ocupando todo el espacio vertical disponible.

Una posible solución seria agregar un padding a .prices. Esto creará un espacio alrededor del contenido, permitiendo que justify-content: center funcione como se esperaba.

```
.prices {
    flex-basis: 700px;
    height: 360px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.185);
    margin: 0px 10px;
    border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.356);
    padding: 50px 10px; /* Añade un padding vertical */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```